# Python script copying a file from a UNC path

Tags: python

I want to read a batch file from a `UNC` path, and what I'm thinking of doing is copying it from that UNC path (something that looks like `\\XXX\AA\BB\CC\batch.bat`) to the local directory where the script is, then using the `open()` function to read it. `cp` doesn't work, so how do I do this? 
Is there a better way than copying then reading?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you read it directly? The UNC path resolution should rely on the system's filesystem functions.

Comment: I found a solution. I can use the open() function directly on the batch file, but I need to double the number of backslashes. Is it because of backslash escapes, since the parameter in open is a string?

Comment: You can do that or you can add `r` at the beginning like this: `r'\\path\to\whatever'` :)

Comment: Yes, backslash is special. If you can do `\n` for a newline, how would you write `\` followed by `n` if you needed to? The answer is, `\\` means a single backslash, so you'd write `\\n`.

Comment: @olyc, if you found an answer, please post it.